# Text-image responsivenes

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have started learning HTML/css about 2 weeks ago and (among others) this is one of the pages I came up with, but I can't make the image to resize when I shrink down the window. Most of the lessons until now have been about HTML and CSS only and how to make the document easy to read for screen readers and I wanted to do some practice with whatever knowledge I had.  Any ideas why the image doesn't shrink down along with the text and why?
Thank you very much!

HTML:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kelly+Slab&display=swap');
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #d89cf6;
}
.top {
    position: relative;
    padding: 1em 2em 1em 2em;
    height: 3em;
    background-color: #3e206d;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-top: solid 6px;
    border-bottom: solid 1px;
}
.top h1 {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: .3em;
    font-family: 'Kelly Slab', cursive;
    font-size: 2.4em;
    color: #f0e3ff;
}
.top ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 1.43em;
}
.top li {
    padding: 0 0.3em;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: .5em;
    position: relative;
}
.top a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #f0e3ff;
    font-family: 'Kelly Slab', cursive;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
.main {
    padding: 1.5em 4.7em 2em;
    color: #000000;
    font-family: 'Kelly Slab', cursive;
}
.main h2 {
    font-size: 1.8rem;
}
.main p {
    font-size: 1.3rem;
}
.main img {
    min-width: auto;
    width: auto;
    max-height: 29em;
    min-height: 25%;
    
}
.text_picture {
    float:right;
    width: auto;
    margin: auto;
}
.thank_you {
    padding: 1.5em 4.7em 2em;
    color: #000000;
    font-family: 'Kelly Slab', cursive;
}
footer {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1.5em 4.7em 2em;
    color: #000000;
    font-family: 'Kelly Slab', cursive;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
   <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Skeleton</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/main.css" type="text/css">
   </head>
   <body>
    <header>
     <div class="top">
      <h1>Arghhhh</h1>
       <nav class="internal_nav">
        <ul> 
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
       </nav>
      </div>    
     </header>
      <section class="main">
       <article>
        <h2>Lorem, ipsum</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi dolore vero natus libero labore! Voluptas, culpa cum animi, explicabo laudantium fuga rem hic fugiat deleniti eveniet ad dignissimos minus! Nisi cumque dolore illo corrupti quo recusandae possimus aliquam officiis blanditiis, inventore veritatis. Cum itaque molestiae iusto dolorem esse illo saepe ipsam dolor cupiditate neque velit, dolore error earum eveniet tempora!
        </p>
         <div id="text_picture_container">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit ab magni officiis eos rem in aperiam tenetur quidem maiores, tempore enim, id sapiente velit pariatur ducimus. Velit vero consequuntur possimus quam culpa voluptatum officia est voluptate eum, labore facilis assumenda rerum harum ipsam facere quas cupiditate. Itaque facilis voluptas cupiditate eos? Commodi odit tempore nihil blanditiis, excepturi quidem vero. Nam nesciunt corporis minima alias aperiam voluptate neque quidem consequatur ab sed, mollitia nulla labore expedita? Laboriosam atque error, similique temporibus eius, sunt quaerat nobis vero maxime corrupti quis ipsam. Aliquam rem id harum culpa nesciunt facere sit atque provident neque!
          </p>
          <div class="text_picture">
           <figure>
            <img src="images/wallpaper-364615676716148alamn2ffq.jpg" alt="lone tree in a field with a orange/magenta sunset in the background">
            <br>
             <figcaption>A lonely tree in the middle of a field, with a really colorful sunset background.
             </figcaption>
            </figure>
           </div>
          </div>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Incidunt earum assumenda praesentium dolor et veritatis libero. Eveniet quasi fugiat, consectetur error possimus natus? Quasi explicabo deserunt quisquam necessitatibus hic aspernatur totam tenetur eveniet accusamus! Voluptate reprehenderit sunt repellat aut adipisci temporibus provident vitae amet cum doloribus dolorum tempora, perferendis voluptas aperiam libero similique distinctio quam corrupti consequatur vero magnam commodi. Enim, consequuntur. Quod maiores laudantium nesciunt doloremque, voluptatem dolorum amet. Tempore, vel dignissimos, veniam magni recusandae saepe ab labore itaque eum officiis, quaerat quae eveniet? Placeat nemo aperiam similique earum, tempore dicta totam atque. Perspiciatis, aut. Ea distinctio iure minima, id doloremque quisquam quidem expedita nemo. Facere dignissimos, architecto similique repellendus aliquid dicta deserunt et esse voluptate nulla ipsum quod earum voluptas nobis consectetur expedita quas, non itaque. Optio incidunt dolor distinctio, ducimus beatae doloribus magni ut aliquam a facere laborum ipsam ratione voluptatem. Dolore modi error nemo impedit recusandae?
          </p>
           <div class="first_survey">
            <form class="survey">
             <fieldset>
              <legend>Chose what impressed you the most:</legend>
               <label for="style">The styling</label>
               <input type="checkbox" id="style" name="survey_choice" value="style">
               <label for="writing">The writing</label>
               <input type="checkbox" id="writing" name="survey_choice" value="writing">
               <label for="pictures">The pictures</label>
               <input type="checkbox" id="writing" name="survey_choice" value="pictures">
               <div class="button">
               <button type="submit">Submit</button>
               </div>
             </fieldset>
            </form>
           </section>            
           <div href="#" class="thank_you">
            <h2>Thank you for taking your time to browse my webpage!
            </h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt quisquam commodi sapiente quos ut unde consectetur alias culpa veniam, quasi perspiciatis expedita esse accusantium quas enim quam soluta, quibusdam sit? Quisquam placeat, iure possimus cupiditate libero non esse quasi facere deserunt debitis delectus reiciendis aliquid magnam a blanditiis, eaque officia.
            <p>
           </div>
          </article>
        </body>   
       <footer>
        <h6>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum, dolore?</h6>
       </footer>
</html>
```

Comment: if your search on google or SO you can find a lot of questions about your problem. like width;100%;height:auto;

Comment: Is not just that. Here I wanted the text to wrap above and below the image aswell.

Comment: It looks like, at first glance, that you have a lot of position: absolute and floats, which removes elements from flow, hence why you can' t resize image.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can always use **VH** unit which stands for viewport width.

[Responsive Text](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_responsive_text)

However, I suggest using **REM** and **EM** units instead, of course, this depends on your needs.

[REM and EM units](http://%20https://css-tricks.com/theres-more-to-the-css-rem-unit-than-font-sizing/)

Feel free to read this article which explains this topic in depth.

[CSS Font Sizing: Pixels vs Em vs Rem vs Percent vs Viewport Units](https://medium.com/@madhum86/css-font-sizing-pixels-vs-em-vs-rem-vs-percent-vs-viewport-units-b1485716afe7)

Now, regarding responsive image sizing, you can simply add a class with these properties and set it to the image you want.

```
.responsive {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

As I said before, read the Medium article, you can use REM, EM, PX, % units on images as well.

Comment: You were right. I had used percentage and made it do exactly what I needed! Thanks alot!